# How to track from which area of ​the website does the users enter a specific page?

Tags: google-analytics, tracking, google-tag-manager, event-tracking

I would like to see from which area of ​​my web site does the users enter a specific page.

For instance, I have this category page: `/Nike-Shoes`. There are many places that the users can enter to this page; Header menu, Main page, Parent category, Footer, Site search...

How can I track how many users entered `/Nike-Shoes` from the header menu, how many of them entered from the site search etc.

Besides this, I also want to track how many of them made a transaction.

So I should be seeing the data like this:

- `/Nike-Shoes` > Header menu > 1000 pageviews > 50 transactions
- `/Nike-Shoes` > Site search > 1500 pageviews > 70 transactions

*As a footnote, I have Enhanced Ecommerce implemented.*

Comment: I don't know about the number of transactions, but have you looked at Behavior->All Pages, choose Landing Page or Previous Page as the secondary dimension?

Comment: I can see the previous page the user clicked but I can't see from which part of the page did the user clicked. For example. /Nike-Shoes is linked from both the header menu and main page. If I check the previous page, analytics will tell me the previous page is "main page". But I have no way to know if the users clicked it from header menu or the body of the main page.

Comment: I assume that it's impractical to add a querystring or event to identify each of these areas?

Answer (score 2):

You may try **Google Analytics**, link [here](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwiV4Obx4pbqAhUPyzgGHQwkALcQFjAAegQIARAC&url=https%3A%2F%2Fanalytics.google.com%2Fanalytics%2Fweb%2F&usg=AOvVaw095EntAfOjiijSk290zWyQ)

Under `Behaviour` → `Behaviour Flow`

---

You may try **Mouseflow**, try [this](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwiC2NfRuJfqAhXGUn0KHX0zDwEQFjAMegQIBhAB&url=https%3A%2F%2Fmouseflow.com%2Fdemo%2F&usg=AOvVaw3GRbPGlMvQHz3Rmq12BZHA)

Comment: This answer is irrelevant to what I asked for. Behavior flow only shows which pages do users click after entering a landing page. You can't see the previous path nor can you see from which location of the page does the user clicks.

Comment: @TheOptimizer I already update my answer

Comment: Thanks I'll try it.